# QHttpResponseHeader is obsolete and removed from Qt5

Tags: qt, network-programming, qt5

In my project, I used [`QHttpResponseHeader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhttpresponseheader.html) in Qt4.8.6, but it became obsolete and it is not
available anymore in Qt5. What is its equivalent class in Qt5?

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent already available in Qt4.8 : look at the [`QNetworkReply`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html) class, particularly the [header()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#header) and [rawHeader()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#rawHeader) functions. It should be what you are looking for.

A bit of explanation : [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) is the class which allows you to send and receive requests. It is much more flexible and not limited to a single protocol, in contrast to QHttp/QFtp. Before, you had to decide on the application level which protocol to use, and now you only pass an URL to the `QNetworkAccessManager`, it will manage the rest.

Comment: A bit of background: `QNetworkAccessManager` was introduced after Qt4 as part of a 4.x release. `QHttp` was then deprecated and is now gone from Qt5.